# how to copy list of strings except string starting with special characters to another list

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python can you please help me with below question

I have a list like this:

```
lst = ["qwerty", "asdf", "   Bird", "#Bird", "Bird", "%qwerty"]
```

I need to copy this into new_lst, where I need to copy only strings starting with alphabets

Ex:

```
new_lst = ["qwerty", "asdf", "Bird"]
```

I dont want to copy any string starting with special character like space,#,& etc

How can I do this

Comment: new_list = [i for i in list if i.isalpha()]

Comment: @HenryYik, the requirement is only the starting char should be an alphabet. So the if condition should be i[0].isalpha(). Right?

Comment: good catch. There is already an answer for that so i'll just leave it as is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using list comprehension :

```
list1 = ["qwerty", "asdf", " Bird", "#Bird", "Bird", "%qwerty"]
list2 = [a for a in list1 if a[0].isalpha()]
```

Try not to assign any variable name as `list`.

**OUTPUT** :

```
['qwerty', 'asdf', 'Bird']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) and [lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)

```
lst = ["qwerty", "asdf", "   Bird", "#Bird", "Bird", "%qwerty"]
new_lst = filter(lambda x: x[0].isalpha() , lst)
print(new_lst)
```

Output

```
['qwerty', 'asdf', 'Bird']
```